# Can I open a port on a single interface (tun0) only while using a UFW profile?

Tags: ufw

So, I know that I can do `ufw allow from tun0 to tun0 port 36892` but is it possible to do something similar while using a UFW profile for multiple ports like
`ports=tun0;36892|tun0;23976|tun0;19827`?

In this case assume that tun0 is 10.8.0.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### The general answer

I'm afraid adding network interface into an application profile is not possible, because under the 'Application Integration' section in [UFW's manual page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/man8/ufw.8.html) for the syntax is written:

> Syntax for the application profiles is a simple .INI format:
>
> ```
> [<name>]
> title=<title>
> description=<description>
> ports=<ports>
> ```

And there is not presented an interface directive.

#### Create Rules manually

According to the question There are two approaches to allow TCP and UDP simultaneously:

1. Add rules for each port separately:

   ```
   sudo ufw allow in on tun0 to any port 36892
   sudo ufw allow in on tun0 to any port 23976
   sudo ufw allow in on tun0 to any port 19827
   ```
2. Add rules for each protocol separately:

   ```
   sudo ufw allow in on tun0 to any port 36892,23976,19827 proto tcp
   sudo ufw allow in on tun0 to any port 36892,23976,19827 proto udp
   ```

To allow access only from a specific address, add `from 10.8.0.xxx` to the declaration - for example:

```
sudo ufw allow in on tun0 from 10.8.0.110 to any port 36892,23976,19827 proto tcp
```

- More examples: [UFW Essentials: Common Firewall Rules and Commands](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/ufw-essentials-common-firewall-rules-and-commands).

#### Create Application profile and create Rules based on it

Let's create a new profile file, called **`custom.ufw.profile`**, located in `/etc/ufw/applications.d/`. The content of this file could looks as this:

```
[CustomApp 1 Full]
title=The first Custom Application
description=Custom Application Description
ports=36892|23976|19827

[CustomApp 1 TCP]
title=The first Custom Application - TPC only
description=Custom Application Description
ports=36892,23976,19827/tcp

[CustomApp 1 UDP]
title=The first Custom Application - UDP only
description=Custom Application Description
ports=36892,23976,19827/udp
```

- We can check if the syntax is correct via the command `ufw app info "app name"`:

  ```
  $ sudo ufw app info "CustomApp 1 Full"
  Profile: CustomApp 1 Full
  Title: The first Custom Application
  Description: Custom Application Description
  Ports:
    36892
    23976
    19827
  ```

Now we can create new rule based on this profile:

```
sudo ufw allow in on tun0 to any app "CustomApp 1 Full"
```

- Check if the rule looks correctly:

  ```
  $ sudo ufw status numbered | grep CustomApp
  [10] CustomApp 1 Full on tun0       ALLOW IN    Anywhere
  [20] CustomApp 1 Full (v6) on tun0  ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
  ```

#### Create custom command to automate the rules enable/disable process

If we intend to have a way for fast enable or disable couple of UFW rules we can create custom command for this purpose. We can use a function that could looks something like this:

```
function ufw-custom {
        if ! ufw_loc="$(type -p "ufw")" || [ -z "$ufw_loc" ]; then
                printf "\nUFW is not installed yet.\n\n"
        elif [ "$1" = "enable" ]; then
                sudo ufw allow in on tun0 to any port 36892
                sudo ufw allow in on tun0 to any port 23976
                sudo ufw allow in on tun0 to any port 19827
                echo ""
                sudo ufw reload
                echo ""
                sudo ufw status numbered
        elif [ "$1" = "disable" ]; then
                sudo ufw delete allow in on tun0 to any port 36892
                sudo ufw delete allow in on tun0 to any port 23976
                sudo ufw delete allow in on tun0 to any port 19827
                echo ""
                sudo ufw reload
                echo ""
                sudo ufw status numbered
        else
                echo ""
                sudo ufw status numbered
                printf "Use 'ufw-custom enable' or 'ufw-custom disable'.\n\n"
        fi
}
export -f ufw-custom
```

Place these lines into the end of `~/.bashrc` file and then `source ~/.bashrc`. Now we have a custom command called `ufw-custom` which can handle `enable` or `disable` as arguments. For example, to enable the rules, use:

```
ufw-custom enable
```

Comment: The question was whether it was possible to do this in a ufw custom profile located in `/etc/ufw/applications.d/custom`

Comment: Hi @Belldandu. I've elaborated the answer. I think the idea from the last section "Create custom command to automate..." would be interest for you.

Comment: Close enough to what I wanted. Didn't know it was possible to restrict a profile to an interface. Thanks.

Comment: To clarify `sudo ufw allow in on tun0 to any app "CustomApp 1 Full"` is what answered my question. Although the automation script is also something I hadnt thought of and may use so thanks for the extra effort on that one.