# How do I allow multiple ports simultaneously in UFW?

Tags: networking, security, iptables, firewall, ufw

I've installed a new Ubuntu 16.04 and enabled `ufw`:

```
ufw enable
```

I tried these ways to unfilter multiple ports at once:

```
ufw allow 22/tcp 25/tcp 80/tcp 443/tcp 9000/tcp
ufw allow 22/tcp, 25/tcp, 80/tcp, 443/tcp, 9000/tcp
ufw allow {22/tcp,25/tcp,80/tcp,443/tcp,9000/tcp}
```

All three ways bring the same error:

> ERROR: Wrong number of arguments

Is it even possible to unfilter multiple ports with UFW?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can allow multiple (TCP **or** UDP) ports in this way:

```
ufw allow 22,25,80,443,9000/tcp
```

Or you can add a range of ports in this way ([source and more explanations](https://askubuntu.com/a/7226/566421)):

```
ufw allow 11200:11299/tcp
```

For more complicated configurations you can create a custom configuration files that could contain one or more custom profiles. For example  ([`man ufw`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/ufw.8.html); [complete example](https://askubuntu.com/a/921631/566421)):

```
$ cat /etc/ufw/applications.d/my-custom-profiles

[MyCustomProfile]
title=Some title
description=Some description
ports=22,25,80,443/tcp|9005:9007/tcp|9000
```

This opens ports 22, 25, 80, 443, 9005-9007 through TCP and port 9000 through TCP and UDP. Note the separate mention of the port range 9005:9007, which is contrary to [what the man page recommends](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/kinetic/en/man8/ufw.8.html#application%20integration). But this is how it works in Debian Bullseye.

You can allow any profile in this way:

```
ufw allow MyCustomProfile
```

Comment: Unfortunately, *this* doesn't seem to work, however: `ufw allow from 192.168.2.0/24 to any port 2049,13025/tcp` Somehow, ufw thinks I'm trying to specify a port range. I was able to do what I needed, however: `ufw allow proto tcp from 192.168.2.0/24 to any port 2049,13025`.  (ufw version 0.36)

Comment: What does `proto ` meant for?

Comment: @alper, it must be shorten from *protocol* - `proto tcp`/`proto udp`..

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with UFW v0.36 (and maybe other versions). The first command returns "ERROR: Wrong number of arguments".

Comment: It looks like the syntax has changed and `ufw allow 11200:11299 proto tcp` must now be `ufw allow 11200:11299/tcp`

Answer (score 3):

For anyone dealing with the message

> WARN: "Invalid ports in profile 'cassandra'"

or just trying to set up Cassandra on UFW in Ubuntu I found the above pa4080 ports= example the only thing I could get to work. Having found that I carefully worked back through it and it seems that for more than one port UFW wants /tcp (or I assume something else equally as valid) on the last port.

```
[cassandra]
title=cassandra ufw rules
description=cassandra needs these ports to run
ports=22,7000,7001,7199,9042,9142,9160/tcp
```

I found this to be the complete, acceptable entry for UFW.

Having spent a fair amount of time on reading the documentation I will follow with my notes that may be of interest.

```
Public port
Port number.    Description  
22            SSH port

Cassandra inter-node ports
Port number.    Description
 7000           Cassandra inter-node cluster communication.
 7001           Cassandra SSL inter-node cluster communication.
 7199           Cassandra JMX monitoring port.

Cassandra client ports
Port number.    Description
 9042           Cassandra client port.
 9160           Cassandra client port (Thrift).
 9142           Default for native_transport_port_ssl, useful when both encrypted and unencrypted connections are required
```

To do this manually:

```
sudo ufw allow 22
sudo ufw allow 7001
sudo ufw allow 7199
sudo ufw allow 7000
sudo ufw allow 9042
sudo ufw allow 9160
sudo ufw allow 9142
```

Ports 7000 and 9042 must be available for external nodes to connect to. 
As a security measure, limit connections to these ports to only the IP addresses
of any other nodes in the cluster.

```
ufw allow proto tcp from [external_node_ip_address] to any port 7000,9042 comment "Cassandra TCP"
```

Next step is `ufw allow from 192.168.0.0/16 to any app cassandra` and test that.

Answer (score 2):

I experimentally found that the message:  "Invalid ports in profile *****"

occurs only if you do not specify the protocol.  For example:

ports=5900:5910 - is incorrect!

ports=5900:5910/tcp - is correct!

This only applies to the situation of specifying a **port range**.

Comment: unless you have multiple ranges, then it wants it only on one of them.